# Is there anyway to make the redirect uri be http for test puprposes for the valid oauth redirect uri in instagram basic display api?

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, instagram-api

I have been trying to make the redirect `URI` be `http://localhost:8080` for test purposes but in vain. is there any way?

Comment: Don’t think they allow that any more. Use a service like https://ngrok.com to create an HTTPS tunnel to your local development machine instead.

Comment: According to Facebook documentation, you can even use a githib link.